# wget content-disposition ubuntu vs alpine

Tags: wget, alpine-linux

In Ubuntu, I can use the following wget flag to get a debian, i.e.,

```
wget --content-disposition https://packagecloud.io/xxxxx/download.deb
dpkg -i ...
```

In Alpine, wget complains that `--content-disposition` isn't valid:

```
wget: unrecognized option: content-disposition
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: wget [-c|--continue] [--spider] [-q|--quiet] [-O|--output-document FILE]
        [--header 'header: value'] [-Y|--proxy on/off] [-P DIR]
        [-S|--server-response] [-U|--user-agent AGENT] [-T SEC] URL...

Retrieve files via HTTP or FTP

        --spider        Only check URL existence: $? is 0 if exists
        -c              Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
        -q              Quiet
        -P DIR          Save to DIR (default .)
        -S              Show server response
        -T SEC          Network read timeout is SEC seconds
        -O FILE         Save to FILE ('-' for stdout)
        -U STR          Use STR for User-Agent header
        -Y on/off       Use proxy
```

In alpine, do I need to download a different "wget"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Alpine Linux, a lot of the common shell tools are replaced by BusyBox.  You can see this is the case with wget by checking the output of the following command:

```
ls -lah $(which wget)
```

In the Alpine install in front of me, that is a symbolic link to `/bin/busybox`

In BusyBox, `wget` does not have the option `--content-disposition`:

```
# wget --help
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: wget [-c|--continue] [--spider] [-q|--quiet] [-O|--output-document FILE]
    [--header 'header: value'] [-Y|--proxy on/off] [-P DIR]
    [-S|--server-response] [-U|--user-agent AGENT] [-T SEC] URL...

Retrieve files via HTTP or FTP

    --spider    Only check URL existence: $? is 0 if exists
    -c      Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
    -q      Quiet
    -P DIR      Save to DIR (default .)
    -S          Show server response
    -T SEC      Network read timeout is SEC seconds
    -O FILE     Save to FILE ('-' for stdout)
    -U STR      Use STR for User-Agent header
    -Y on/off   Use proxy
```

You will also find that GNU `wget` is available in the official Alpine repositories, so to get the full version it is as simple as:

```
apk update
apk add wget
```

And then you have GNU `wget` installed, which should behave more like it does on other systems you have used:

```
# wget --help | grep -A1 content-disposition
       --content-disposition       honor the Content-Disposition header when
                                     choosing local file names (EXPERIMENTAL)
```

Comment: yep in the error I have above, it points to busybox, didn't know that the busybox wget wasn't "full", thanks!